# How to ensure the high quality texture when zooming the 3D model in opengl es

Tags: opengl-es, zooming, textures

I have some troubles about ensure the quality texture when zooming in the 3d model with texturing the image two-dimensional image in opengl ES  while have decided to ask for help!

I have loading the .obj format text file and texturing by 1024*1024 image. I can arbitrary rotation and scale the 3d model with texture.But when scale to certain degree,texture is shown that low quality.

How can i ensure the high quality texture?
  What good method to solve this problem?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you doing about mipmaps?  What kind of texture are you trying to create?  Is greater detail available, or can you apply a repeating texture to a smaller area?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have learned about mipmaps,which to solve  minimizes aliasing effects and assures continuity within and between target images.used a 2048 * 2048 2-D image for 3-D model's texture mapping. //[the code]
     GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);  
     GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maNormalHandle);  
     GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTexCoorHandle); 
     //[bind texture]
     GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
     GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
     GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vCount);

Comment: Has this solved your problem?

Comment: i can't achieve in technology, can you share any code about it by opengl-es 2.0.